# Does it make sense to always use Straight_JOIN distinct?

Tags: php

Before posting this question i searched on SOF, but couldn't find something specific to me.  I am doing basic `SELECT * FROM table WHERE this = '$that'` kind of queries.  But sometimes i have noticed in the queries that a result will show multiple times and its the samething thats just being repeated.  So does it make sense to always use STRAIGHT_JOIN distinct when doing queries?

Comment: What is STRAIGHT_JOIN distinct?  What RDBMS is this?

Comment: Depends. What exactly would make it better or worse for your situation? Have done any profiling on your queries to compare it with a normal JOIN? You say 'specific to me' but you are not being very specific ;)

Answer (score -1):

No. Use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) instead.

For example

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE this = '$that' GROUP BY colum_which_is_repeated
```